# Test Class Error - CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting this error message and can't seem to figure out what is causing it.  I have a test class where I am creating a new Task record.  In my sandbox the test class passes fine, but in production during deployment I get this error:

"System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, TaskAction: data changed by trigger for field Task Record Type ID: value not valid for the entity: Task: []
"

```
 Task newTask = new Task();
 newTask.Subject = 'Test Task';
 newTask.WhatId = opp.Id;
 newTask.WhoId = con.Id;
 newTask.Status = 'Open';
 newTask.Priority = 'High';
 newTask.Type = 'Call';

 insert newTask;
```

The variables **opp.Id** and **con.Id** are the IDs after inserting dummy contact and opportunity records that part of the dummy data set used in my test class.

Comment: Where are you setting the recordTypeId to the task?

Comment: I am not setting recordTypeId anymore.  Originally, I had a line in there and was getting the above error.  I removed that line of code that was explicitly setting it, but I still get the error for some reason.  I verified in production by looking at the failed deployment and can confirm that RecordtypeId is not in the test class code anymore when creating a Task

Comment: Did you check in production if there is any automation trying to set the record type?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing I am seeing production, workflows, flows, and process builder.   If I run the insert code for creating a new task in an anonymous window in production I can create the task just fine, but for some reason when it runs in the test class I get this error.

Comment: probably you just deployed the old changeset containing the id. try creating a new changeset.

Comment: Good idea, tried it, but still failing with same error.  "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, TaskAction: data changed by trigger for field Task Record Type ID: value not valid for the entity: Task: []"

Comment: Solved the issue, I had hardcoded the RecordTypeId in the Trigger, and IDs are not always the same between sandbox and prod so that was the issue.  I modified the Trigger code to get the ID using Schema..SObjectType.Task.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('MyRecordType').getRecordTypeId()

Comment: NEVER EVER use hardcoded ids in code